# How do you count the amount of documents in a MongoDB collection within Node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Quite an odd situation, I've tried numerous solutions and I can't seem to crack it.

A lot of the resources I've found only include **mongo** console commands, I'm not sure how you'd write this in Node.js.

*The reason I'm trying to work this out is I'm trying to make each documents 'id' iterate from the last, so the attempt is to find the amount of documents in a collection, add one and then use that number as the 'id' for the new document.*

Comment: What MongoDB driver and/or library are you using in Node.js?

Comment: You are going about this in the wrong way. You want a collection ( really likely a single document ) containing the "counter" value. See: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/. Also there is a mongoose plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment

Comment: I'm using Mongoose & I'll research this other method. It mentions that this isn't a good idea if you begin to deal with a large number of documents.

Comment: The reasoning why an "integer" as a primary key is not a good idea for a large amount of documents is a universal concept to all databases and also a primary concern in the default selection of `ObjectId` for that value in MongoDB collections. Numeric counters have finite limits that are dwarfed by alternate means. So the recommendation is meant to emplore you to retain the `ObjectId`. For clarification.

Comment: Ah, that clears things up, thank you.

Comment: We are talking about MongoDB here, a database designed to handle a huge amount of data, potentially distributed across a large number of servers. So doing queries like "give me all documents" or "make sure a specific number is unique across all my documents", aren't suppose to be things you should be doing.

Comment: Well I'm trying to keep some sort of order, I'm very new to using MongoDB (evidently) and I'm not aware of any alternatives. I wanted to give each thing a unique identifier that worked numerically so that I can use that to represent each document. In my use case, I'm using it to store data (author/path of file) of the uploaded files. First uploaded file has the id of 1, second uploaded is 2, I can't think of a better system than to have each document having an id that is one higher than the id of the previous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the number of documents in a collection, use `db.collection.find({}).count()`.

However, what you are trying to do will not work. When you have a lot of parallel accesses to the database, then it is possible that multiple threads do this at the same time, receive the same count and will thus insert a document with the same id. According to the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem), a distributed database like MongoDB can not provide this kind of consistency.

What you should do instead is rely on MongoDB [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)'s as unique identifiers for documents. MongoDB generates these automatically for each document when you don't provide an own value for `_id`. ObjectId's are globally unique (unique enough for any practical purpose), so you won't get any collisions. They also begin with a timestamp, so when you order by `_id` you get a roughly chronological order (as previously stated, a *strict* chronological order is impossible to provide by a distributed system).

As a rule of thumb, whenever you would use `AUTO_INCREMENT` in SQL, you would likely use ObjectId's in MongodDB.

Comment: Exactly the sort of answer I was looking for. Fantastic answer and great feedback.