# Auto increase in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-populate

I have a Model : **OrderEventSchema**

```
var OrderEventSchema = new Schema(
    {
        orderId:        { type: String, required: true },
        sequence:       { type: Number },
        workflowId:     { type: String, required: true },
        type:           { type: String },
        transitionId:   { type: String },
        placeId:        { type: String },
        eventType:      { type: String },
        payLoad:        { type: Schema.Types.Mixed }
    }, options
);
```

Handle Post save :

```
OrderEventSchema.post('save', function(doc) {
    getNextSequence(doc.orderId)
        .then(function(nextSequence) {
            doc.sequence = nextSequence;
            doc.save();
        })
})

function getNextSequence (orderId) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        orderEvent.findOne({
            orderId             : orderId
        }).sort({'sequence' : -1}).limit(1).exec(function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(doc.sequence ? doc.sequence + 1 : 1);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Now, everything I save, it will get a infinite loop, can anyone help me, how can I increase the `sequence` without using another module, how can I improve this code.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you count the amount of documents in a MongoDB collection within Node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669811/how-do-you-count-the-amount-of-documents-in-a-mongodb-collection-within-node) (the author actually wants to do the same thing: auto-increment in mongodb)

Comment: The `sequence` isn't for ID of this model, because I want after increase `sequence` by 1 then I will create a Snapshot of the model based on sequence. 
Ex: from 1 -> 5